# Cannot convert "TextAlignment.Center" into Xamarin.Forms.TextAlignment

Tags: xamarin.forms

When I did following code:
TextAlignmentConverter textAlignmentConverter = new TextAlignmentConverter();
var abc = (TextAlignment)(textAlignmentConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString("TextAlignment.Center"));

I got error message:
System.InvalidOperationException
Message=Cannot convert "TextAlignment.Center" into Xamarin.Forms.TextAlignment

Any ideas? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.textalignmentconverter?view=xamarin-forms)

> This converter recognizes and converts string representations of the
> FlowDirection enumeration, as well as the following strings,
> regardless of case: "left", "right", and "**center**".

use "Center", not "TextAlignment.Center"